# Night light is always on in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10

When I log on to my account in Windows 10, some sort of night mode starts up after a few seconds, irregardless if it is the middle of the day. Chekcing the settings tells me it is disabled. If I turn it on, the effect is doubled, and my screen turns to a dark deep red color.

Not sure what's going on.

Comment: I've found a temporary way to circumwent it. I log in to my account, press Win+L and log in to a different account, hit Win+L again and switch back to my account. This, for some reason, makes my screen normal again...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out what is going on. It is a bug... : https://mspoweruser.com/cumulative-update-kb4512941-delivers-bizarre-new-orange-screenshots-bug/